# Transparent problem

Tags: materials, shaders, image, transparency, settings

I have a problem with transparent image, I have tried to follow so many tutorials but no one has found a solution to my problem. I am using a png image. Alpha clip is on. If you want picture of another screenshots write me.Thank you for answer.[image]

Comment: could you share this file with texture? **File > External data > Pack resources** and sent it here.

Comment: If you're using Eevee, for all transparent material you need to go in the Material panel > Settings > Blend Mode > Alpha Blend

Comment: Please share blend file, could be different reasons. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you use nodes but you don't. In the Surface tab click on the Use nodes button.